# Синхронизация потока хоста и видеокарты в CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

Имеется следующий код. Он исполняется в потоке хоста(CPU). Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы поток CPU ждал того момента, пока две функции на видеокарте не завершат свою работу. На данный момент поток хоста не ждет завершения работы этих двух функций и просто выводит в качестве итогового времени "1". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
float time = 1;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);

cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
//-------------------GPU------------------------------------
DirectMoveMP << <1, n >> > (dev_a2, dev_b2, dev_n);
InversMoveMP << <1, n >> > (dev_a2, dev_x2, dev_b2, dev_n);
//----------------------------------------------------------
//cudaEventSynchronize();
//cudaThreadSynchronize();
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaStatus = cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вызов пользовательских куда функций обычно асинхронный, соответственно они возвращаются не дожидаясь окончания вычислений. Чтобы дождаться окончания выполнения всех вычислений на стороне GPU необходимо вызвать `cudaDeviceSynchronize`.

Comment: Если нужно было вызвать этот метод перед cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);, то это не помогло...

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов вызов cudaEventRecord тоже асинхронный. А вообще чтобы просто измерить время используйте таймер из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: ну да. Если он асинхронный, то вызов метода cudaDeviceSynchronize как раз таки застопорит программу пока не функции не выполнятся на GPU, как только выполнится - вызовется cudaEventRecord, мне кажется или логика все таки правильная? И насчет стандартной библиотеки, то как я это сделаю, если мне все равно это придется вызывать в потоке хоста?

Comment: И, наверное, скажу, cudaError_t cudaStatus выводит следующее: an illegal memory access was encountered. Может быть моя проблема не в том, что синхронизация не верна?

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов event также можно синхронизировать вызовом cudaEventSynchronize, а если вы хотите упорядочить вызовы что-бы что-то замерить, то точек синхронизации должно быть три - после первого cudaEventRecord, после кернелов, и после второго cudaEventRecord. Так а что помешает использовать таймер из стандартной библиотеки?

Comment: Этот таймер позволит посчитать время выполнения на GPU?

Comment: @НикитаСкворцов время выполнения на GPU = время прошедшее с вызова кернела до возврата cudaDeviceSynchronize. А вообще для cuda есть профайлер

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113815/discussion-between---and-user7860670).